# Automated Build: Creating a Windows store application including pdb files

Tags: tfs, debug-symbols, pdb-files, appx

I currently have a TFS build job that builds a appx file for sideloading to a Windows 8.1. I would like to add the pdb files (debug symbols) into the appx file.

Currently when I look into my bin directory I do see the pdb files there, but when I build the appx and look inside of it I don't see the files there.

Is there a way to do this? A MSBuild parameter? Or a Manifest change?

Please help.